# Type Checking in Both Directions

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm writing some code in TypeScript and I want to create an interface that allows type checking in both directions in other functions.

I want to write functions that only accept valid team roles, and other functions that only accept valid team member names. In my angular component, I want to display the TeamMemberName in the HTML template, but do logic based on the TeamMemberRole.

My current solution works, but is convoluted and I don't know how it can be simplified. Any suggestions? Should I use an interface, a class ,the keyof operator?

```
export type TeamMemberName = 'Kathy' | 'Bob' | 'Sally';
export type TeamMemberRole = 'Manager' | 'Secretary' | 'Engineer';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TeamMemberService{

  constructor() { } 

  public getRole(name: TeamMemberName) : TeamMemberRole {
    switch (name) {
      case "Kathy": {
        return "Manager";
        break;
      }
      case "Bob": {
        return "Secretary";
        break;
      }
      case "Sally": {
        return "Engineer";
        break;
      }
      default: {
        throw new Error("Not a recognized Team Member.");
      }
    }
  }

  public getName(name: TeamMemberRole ) : TeamMemberName{
    switch (name) {
      case "Manager": {
        return "Kathy";
        break;
      }
      case "Secretary": {
        return "Bob";
        break;
      }
      case "Engineer": {
        return "Sally";
        break;
      }
      default: {
        throw new Error("Not a recognized Team Role.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not very realistic. In a typical company, there are more than 3 people, and you can't know in advance all the possible names of the employees. You should probably just have an Array<Employee>, where Employee is an interface with a name (of type string, because a name can be any string), and a role (of type TeamMemberRole). Then use the Array filter method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find employees by name and by role.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you. And yes, I see how a string name type would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands you have only defined types that represent a `TeamMemberName` and a `TeamMemberRole`.

What you need next are objects that store data in those types, let's create a type to represent such an object:

```
export interface TeamMember {
    name: TeamMemberName;
    role: TeamMemberRole;
}
```

Now that we have a type that represents our desired data structure, let's put some test objects in the `TeamMemberService`:

```
private teamMembers: TeamMember[] = [
    { name: 'Kathy', role: 'Manager' },
    { name: 'Bob', role: 'Engineer' },
    { name: 'Sally', role: 'Secretary' }
];
```

Now, for example, when a call is made to the `getRole` method we can do something like this:

```
getRole(name: TeamMemberName) : TeamMemberRole {
   const member = this.teamMembers.find(member => member.name === name);

   if(!member) {
      throw new Error('Not a recognized Team Member.');
   }

   return member.role;
}
```

I would like to point out that having a type constrained to preset values for the member name is probably not realistic however, and you may want to consider making it just a string.

Note: This will only return the **first** match. If you want to return all matching employees, then consider `array.filter()` instead of `array.find()` and change the return type to `TeamMemberRole[]` as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its a one-to-one mapping between the name and role of team members, the following code snippet using Map should work fine.

```
export type TeamMemberName = 'Kathy' | 'Bob' | 'Sally';
```

export type TeamMemberRole = 'Manager' | 'Secretary' | 'Engineer';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TeamMemberService {

```
private teamMembers: Map<TeamMemberRole, TeamMemberName>;

constructor() {
    this.teamMembers = new Map<TeamMemberRole, TeamMemberName>();
    this.teamMembers.set('Manager', 'Kathy');
    this.teamMembers.set('Secretary', 'Bob');
    this.teamMembers.set('Engineer', 'Sally');
}

public getRole(memberName: TeamMemberName): TeamMemberRole {
    let teamMemberRole: TeamMemberRole;
    if (name) {
        this.teamMembers.forEach((name: TeamMemberName, role: TeamMemberRole) => {
            if (name === memberName) {
                teamMemberRole = role;
            }
        });
    }
    if (!teamMemberRole) {
        throw new Error('Not a recognized Team Member.');
    }
    return teamMemberRole;
}

public getName(role: TeamMemberRole): TeamMemberName {
    if (role) {
        return this.teamMembers.get(role);
    }
    throw new Error('Not a recognized Team Member.');
}
```

}